# How to zip and unzip zip files between linux host and windows

Tags: php

I have lot's of problem with ziping and unziping zip files between xammp windows server and linux host.
What's the way to zip files in xammp on windows and unzip it in linux host and vise versa?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has built-in extension for zipping and unzipping:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
?>
```

Comment: ,Yes I know that But when you make a zip file from xammp in windows it's not correct in linux host because of folders inside that zip file.

Comment: Your ZIP files will be zipped in Linux host in the future when project is released. So don't bother such thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Zippy](https://github.com/alchemy-fr/Zippy) it abstracts the platform and does a good job, BTW, it supports a couple of compression methods, please take a look at it.

**Archive listing and extraction:**

```
use Alchemy\Zippy\Zippy;

$zippy = Zippy::load();
$zippy->create('archive.zip', '/path/to/folder');

$archive = $zippy->open('build.tar');

// extract content to `/tmp`
$archive->extract('/tmp');

// iterates through members
foreach ($archive as $member) {
    echo "archive contains $member \n";
}
```

**Archive creation**

```
use Alchemy\Zippy\Zippy;

$zippy = Zippy::load();
// creates an archive.zip that contains a directory "folder" that contains
// files contained in "/path/to/directory" recursively
$archive = $zippy->create('archive.zip', array(
    'folder' => '/path/to/directory'
), recursive = true);
```

Comment: I came here because Alchemy\Zippy fails for me on Windows. Does it work on Windows for you?

Comment: I haven't tested it on Windows but I would be surprised if it fails only on Windows. There could be few things you can do:

1. I would recommend you to check the path configuration
2. Check the error log and understand the problem